# how to write query to check status is present in list or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Declare Status varchar(15)

set status = 'Returned','Cancelled','Rejected'

I pass parameter 'processing' and 'Completed'

I want to find out 'processing' and 'Completed' is presented in Status group or not.

if it is presented true true else false.

plz help me ....

Comment: You'd have to give some information on your table structure for people to be able to help you.

Comment: But there is neither `processing` nor `completed` status in the status options.

Comment: He wants a query to tell him "TRUE" if 'Processing' is in his status column, and "FALSE" if not.  Same for 'Completed'.

Answer (score 1):

You could use exists.  Guessing at your structure a bit but:

```
if exists(Select status from mytable where status = "Completed")
Begin
(Your code here)
End
```